# Add multiple products to cart - WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've set up a quote bulk purchase quote form using JavaScript. It does all the calculations and displays the figures I need it to but I can't get WooCommerce to allow me to create a single URL that will add up to 3 products to the cart at once each with their own quantity.

For example a customer might enter:

productID: quantity
Product15: 9
Product17: 12
Product19: 3

Currently each Product has its own Add to Cart button using the WooCommerce URL structure: '.com?add-to-cart=Product15&quantity=9'

I did find [this](https://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/) which when I put the code into functions.php allowed me to add multiple products but with the same quantity. So this allowed me to do '.com?add-to-cart=Product15,Product17&quantity=9' and add nine of Product15 and Product17 to the cart. However if I was to try this '.com?add-to-cart=Product15,Product17&quantity=9,12' both products would be added to the cart but each would have a quantity of nine.

This wouldn't be a massive issue if the page didn't reload each time the 'Add to Cart' button was clicked. The reload means the form goes blank and the customer has to then re-enter their information. I did try to use URL parameters to set the Value attribute of the Input but for such a simple problem I couldn't find a simple answer. I was going to have the 'Get Quote' button generate the link for each 'Add to Cart' button with args for refilling the quote form when the page reloaded, for example the generated URL would look like this '.com?add-to-cart=Product15&quantity=9&P17qty=12&P19qty=3'

So my question(s):
a) How do I create a single button that will add multiple products to the cart with user defined quantities for each product?
-or-
b) How do I get my URL parameters into my input areas? Using WordPress.

Here's the current code for the quote form, sorry if it isn't pretty. I'm still learning so I'm sure it could probably be done in a neater way :)

HTML:

```
<H2 STYLE="COLOR:WHITE;MARGIN-TOP:0;">YOUR FULL QUOTE - £<span id="totalquote"></span></H2>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>2 Pack Qty:<br><input type="text" id="qty2pks" value="0"><br>Quote - £<span id="2pk">0</span></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button>Add to Cart</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="4pksqty">4 Pack Qty:<br><input type="text" name="qty4pks" value="0" id="qty4pks"><br>Quote - £<span id="4pk">0</span></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="thislink">Add to Cart</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>1 Pack Qty:<br><input type="text" id="qty1pks" value="0"><br>Quote - £<span id="1pk">0</span></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button>Add to Cart</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <P><button onclick="runQuote()" value="Get Quote">Get Quote</button></P>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>

var qty1pk = document.getElementById('qty1pks').value;
var qty2pk = document.getElementById('qty2pks').value;
var qty4pk = document.getElementById('qty4pks').value;
var price1pk = 9.99;
var price2pk = 14.99;
var price4pk = 19.99;
var discdec1 = 0.1;
var discdec2 = 0.125;
var quote2pk = (price2pk - (price2pk * discdec1)) * qty2pk;
var quote4pk = (price4pk - (price4pk * discdec1)) * qty4pk;
var quote1pk = (price1pk - (price1pk * discdec1)) * qty1pk;
var fullquote = quote4pk + quote2pk + quote1pk;
var fullquotedec = parseFloat(Math.round(fullquote * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

document.getElementById("2pk").innerHTML = quote2pk.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("4pk").innerHTML = quote4pk.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("1pk").innerHTML = quote1pk.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("totalquote").innerHTML = fullquotedec;

function runQuote() {
    var qty1pk = document.getElementById('qty1pks').value;
    var qty2pk = document.getElementById('qty2pks').value;
    var qty4pk = document.getElementById('qty4pks').value;
    var price1pk = 9.99;
    var price2pk = 14.99;
    var price4pk = 19.99;
    var discdec1 = 0.1;
    var discdec2 = 0.125;
    if (qty2pk <= 4) {
        var quote2pk = price2pk * qty2pk;
    } else if (qty2pk <= 10) {
        var quote2pk = (price2pk - (price2pk * discdec1)) * qty2pk;
    } else if (qty2pk >= 11) {
        var quote2pk = (price2pk - (price2pk * discdec2)) * qty2pk;
    }
    if (qty4pk <= 4) {
        var quote4pk = price4pk * qty4pk;
    } else if (qty4pk <= 10) {
        var quote4pk = (price4pk - (price4pk * discdec1)) * qty4pk;
    } else if (qty4pk >= 11) {
        var quote4pk = (price4pk - (price4pk * discdec2)) * qty4pk;
    }
    if (qty1pk <= 4) {
        var quote1pk = price1pk * qty1pk;
    } else if (qty1pk <= 10) {
        var quote1pk = (price1pk - (price1pk * discdec1)) * qty1pk;
    } else if (qty1pk >= 11) {
        var quote1pk = (price1pk - (price1pk * discdec2)) * qty1pk;
    }
    var fullquote = quote4pk + quote2pk + quote1pk;
    var fullquotedec = parseFloat(Math.round(fullquote * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    var url = "http://www.handiiproducts.com/professionalmultibuy-options/?add-to-cart=35&quantity=" + encodeURIComponent(qty4pk);
    var element = document.getElementById('thislink');
    element.setAttribute("href", url);

    document.getElementById("2pk").innerHTML = quote2pk.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("4pk").innerHTML = quote4pk.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("1pk").innerHTML = quote1pk.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("totalquote").innerHTML = fullquotedec;

}

</script>
```

Comment: You need to do it with ajax. Follow this : https://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/woocommerce-add-to-cart-with-quantity-and-ajax/